# How can I validate user-input in a JField in java

Tags: java, swing, validation

I've been trying to make a Sign Up form in java SWING but as I wanted to verify the user inputs from the JComponents, I was not able to get it to work.

I've tried parsing the field.getText but it didn't work as the IDE ignored the parsing. I looked up the InputVerifier Class but it made no sense as it was doing the same thing I did.

```
public static void checkDataDouble(JTextField weightField, JTextField desiredWeightField)throws NumberFormatException{
        String weightValue = weightField.getText();
        String desiredWeightValue = desiredWeightField.getText();
        Double.parseDouble(weightValue);
        Double.parseDouble(desiredWeightValue);
    }
```

Comment: "*but it didn't work as the IDE ignored the parsing"* - no, you didn't assign the values to anything. You might consider having a look at [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: If I got you, you want to check if the value is number, so Double.parseDouble should do the work.. why it didn't work ?